# MATLAB: Simple string analysis - Find locations

Tags: string, matlab, datatable, find, location

Here I have an example of a piece of literature that I would like to do a simple analysis on. Notice the different sections:

```
str =   "Random info - at beginning-man. "+ ...
        "Random info still continues. "+ ...
        "CHAPTER 1. " + ...
        "Random info in middle one, "+ ...
        "Random info still continues. "+ ...
        "1 This is sentence one of verse one, "+ ...
        "This still sentence one of verse one. "+ ...
        "2 This is sentence one of verse two. "+ ...
        "This is sentence two of verse two. "+ ...
        "3 This is sentence one of verse three; "+ ...
        "this still sentence one of verse three. "+ ...
        "CHAPTER 2. " + ...
        "Random info in middle two. "+ ...
        "Random info still continues. "+ ...
        "1 This is sentence four? "+ ...
        "2 This is sentence five, "+ ...
        "3 this still sentence five but verse three!"+ ...
        "Random info at end's end."+ ...
        "Random info still continues. ";
```

I'm interested all the data dat can be called "Random info in middle", which is after a Chapter name, and before a verse beginning.

I would like to use the function "extractBetween" to extract the information found between "CHAPTER #" and "1"(First Verse).

I know how to use the function "extractBetween", but how can I determine the locations just before "CHAPTER #" and just after "1"(First Verse), for any amount of Chapters?

At the end I would like to have such an answer, where the random information for each Chapter is allocated in a table:

[image]

I've tried, regexp() and findstr(), but have no success.
All help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: **Deleting your previous identical questions does not make posting duplicates OK!** As I commented only hours ago... Please don't post exact duplicates to previous questions - I think the issue here limiting your responses is that your question is too broad. If you can boil this down to the fundamental problem(s) you're having then you will either be able to solve them or make it easier for us.i.e. include a [mcve] (note *minimal*), why it's not working, what you don't understand specifically. You're asking for a fairly generic text parser, which is a project rather than a short Q&A

Comment: Sorry, I did have a somewhat similar question, but not a duplicate. Stackoverflow marked it as a "duplicate" (Probably because I used the same string(str), as seen above), but for a different problem. I could not get rid of the problem of being marked as "duplicate", while not being, so I needed to delete both questions and decided just to ask the one above. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with [`regexp`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btqcwmp-6) to match the text.

```
[tokens, matches] = regexp(str, '(CHAPTER \d)\.\s*(.*?)1', 'tokens', 'match');

for k = 1:numel(tokens)
    fprintf('%s\t%s\n', tokens{k}(1), tokens{k}(2)); 
    % or: fprintf('%s\t%s\n', tokens{k}); 
end
```

Will print

```
CHAPTER 1   Random info in middle one, Random info still continues. 
CHAPTER 2   Random info in middle two. Random info still continues.
```

To explain the regular expression `(CHAPTER \d)\.\s*(.*?)1`:

- `(CHAPTER \d)` matches CHAPTER with any number, and the () brackets surrounding it will capture the match  in the `tokens` variable.
- `\.` matches the period
- `\s*` matches any possible whitespace
- `(.*?)1` will capture any text till the next 1 in the text. Note the questionmark to make it match lazy, otherwise it will match all the text till the last 1 in `str`.

Comment: Thank you once more. Just one quick question. What if, lets say a chapter does not have "Random middle info"? For example, I run into problems once I remove the two lines of code after `"CHAPTER 1. " + ...` Let me know if you would like me to open a new question?