# Matlab: Simple regexp expression use problem

Tags: regex, matlab, if-statement, datatable

I believe I have a simple problem. This is a data sample of a literature work that I would like to divide up:

```
WholeBook = "Random info - at beginning-man. "+ ...
        "Random info still continues. "+ ...
        "CHAPTER 1 " + ...
        "1 This is sentence one of verse one, "+ ...
        "This still sentence one of verse one. "+ ...
        "2 This is sentence one of verse two. "+ ...
        "This is sentence two of verse two. "+ ...
        "3 This is sentence one of verse three; "+ ...
        "this still sentence one of verse three. "+ ...
        "CHAPTER 2 " + ...
        "Random info in middle two. "+ ...
        "Random info still continues again. "+ ...
        "1 This is sentence four? "+ ...
        "2 This is sentence five, "+ ...
        "3 this still sentence five but verse three!"+ ...
        "Random info at end's end.";
```

I would like to divide the following data in a table like this (This is how the solution should look):

[image]

However, my current solution looks like this:

[image]

Thus row 1 is incorrect, but row 2 is correct. Otherwise said, my solution works if there is indeed information after "CHAPTER #", but not if there is no information. This is the code that produced this solution:

```
[tokens, RandomInfoMiddle] = regexp(WholeBook, '(CHAPTER \d)\s*(.*?)1', 'tokens', 'match');
RandomInfoMiddle = RandomInfoMiddle';
RandomInfoMiddle = regexprep(RandomInfoMiddle,'CHAPTER \d+ (.+) \d$','$1'); %Delete "Chapter+Nr" + ...1
            % To explain the regular expression (CHAPTER \d)\.\s*(.*?)1:
            % (CHAPTER \d) matches CHAPTER with any number, and the () brackets surrounding it will capture the match in the tokens variable.
            % \. matches the period
            % \s* matches any possible whitespace
            % (.*?)1 will capture any text till the next 1 in the text. Note the question mark to make it match lazy, otherwise it will match all the text till the last 1 in str.
```

Please help me find a solution as described in the first picture/table.
(I suspect the use of an if statement coupled with the correct regexp expression.)

All help is appreciated.

Comment: You have asked several many similar questions over the last few months ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64135909/3978545), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64172466/3978545), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64180034/3978545), ...). If these aren't helping you to help yourself then consider trying to reframe what you are asking, and/or pick up a good book on regular expressions! Note that you haven't described your aim well here, just how to get a very specific output with little context why, this will hinder you if you want a generic solution which is more helpful for you in the future

Comment: Perhaps like this `^(CHAPTER \d+)\r?\n((?:(?!\d+\b).*(?:\r?\n|$))+)` https://regex101.com/r/qc4LHr/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```matlab
>> tokens = regexp(WholeBook, 'CHAPTER \d+\s*(.*?)(?:1|\z)', 'tokens', 'match');
>> tokens
tokens =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] =
  }

  [1,2] =
  {
    [1,1] = Random info in middle two.
Random info still continues again.

  }
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wMmKGJ/1). Note there is no need using two capturing groups, you only need one.

The regex matches:

- `CHAPTER` - a word to match and then a space
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?:1|\z)` - `1` or end of string.